# Joda: parse string as DateTime with weird timezone format

Tags: java, jodatime

Is there a valid joda `DateTimeFormat` for date strings like the following:

> Mon, 23 Jul 2018 07:08:26 +0300 GMT

I have tried:

```
DateTimeFormatter FMT1 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
DateTimeFormatter FMT2 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
DateTimeFormatter FMT3 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z Z");
```

but none of these work.
I had a look in here https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html  and I cannot figure out a way to parse that date without having to change the string itself first. 
Is there a way?

Comment: I can't find that pattern in Joda. If you can use java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter ther is a standard one for that pattern: RFC_1123_DATE_TIME. See here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: @rick WIth two (conflicting) offsets `+0300` and `GMT` is doesn’t exactly match `RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`.

Comment: That's the offset is not conflicting. Open the description of the format from the doc and you will see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME

Comment: @rick I tried parsing the string with that formatter and got an exception because of unparsed text, pointing to the space between `+0300` and `GMT`. You are right that it is close. Also close enough that you could use that formatter, you’d just need to parse in a a way where you didn’t insist on parsing the entire string (which I’d consider a little bit of a hack).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it that `+0300` is the true offset and `GMT` is just there to say that `+0300` is relative to GMT. Joda-Time supports apostrophes for delimiting constant text that shouldn’t be interpreted:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z 'GMT'");

    DateTime dt = DateTime.parse("Mon, 23 Jul 2018 07:08:26 +0300 GMT", formatter);
    System.out.println(dt);
```

Output on my computer in Europe/Copenhagen time zone:

> 2018-07-23T06:08:26.000+02:00

As an aside the idea of using a lowercase and an uppercase `z` wasn’t too bad. It works if you put them in the opposite order:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z z");
```

> 2018-07-23T04:08:26.000Z

I prefer the apostrophes, though. It’s hard for a reader to know what to expect from `Z z`.